# Flex box skip height calculation for specific children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex box div containing (black border) several child divs (green, blue, red). The height of the children is defined by the their content. Normally the height of the parent is the height of the biggest child.
In my use case I need to be able to skip some children (green) for the parents height calculation and cut those children's height overflow.
In contrast to the example I don't want to set fixed values for height.

[image: example]

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.a2 {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.b {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: green;
}

.c {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
}

.d {
  height: 250px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
is situation:
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
  </div>
  <div class="c">
  </div>
  <div class="d">
  </div>
</div>
target situation:
<div class="a2">
  <div class="b">
  </div>
  <div class="c">
  </div>
  <div class="d">
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhcvju1d/)

Comment: No you would need javascript for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The children you want flexbox to "ignore" could be set as `relative`ly positioned containers with no height, and inside them an `absolute`ly positioned element. Since the position is `absolute`, the black square will ignore its overflow.

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.a2 {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.b {
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.b .b-child {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: green;
}

.c {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
}

.d {
  height: 250px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <!--The one you want to "ignore" -->
    <div class="b-child"></div>
    <!--The absolutely positioned child -->
  </div>
  <div class="c">
  </div>
  <div class="d">
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxs8z92b/11/)

Then add `overflow: hidden` to the main container so the green line won't overflow.

Comment: The "solution" does not meet the intended outcome. `overflow: hidden` cuts away the green element not allowing it to leave the parent element.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` is actually optional

Answer (score 0):

Use negative bottom margin to do this:

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.b {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom:-300px; /* a big value here */
}

.c {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: blue;
}

.d {
  height: 250px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
  </div>
  <div class="c">
  </div>
  <div class="d">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your idea. It also works in my simplified test case but I had some problems in my productive use case, which is little more complex (Text in the green box which should be cut off at the end of the parent div). MaybeI should mention this next time. But I didn't had much hope to find an solution for the simplefied example ;-)

Comment: @ChristophLarisch you should always add your *real* use case to get accurate answers. I am sure at 100% that my approach will also work but the code would be a bit different if you code was too

Comment: You're right thank you ;-) I will keep this in mind for the next question. In my complete use case there ist rotated text in the green box, which should be cut of at the bottom end of the parent div (with ellipsis). I couldn't to get it to work with the margin.